# C++ NetBeans Linking External Sources and .so Files

Tags: c++, netbeans, linker, shared-libraries

I am writing a C++ program in Linux with NetBeans.  I am having difficulty setting it up to use external sources/shared objects.  I have the .so files from the compiled external package and the source files that go with it.

So far I have:

- specified for the project to include all the source and header file directories (under Project properties->Build->C++ Compiler)
- specified the .so files that correspond to the external source code (under Project properties->Build-Linker)

When I try to declare an object defined in the external sources NetBeans does not give me any syntax errors and even auto-completes the object name for me.  However, when I build the program I get an error saying "undefined reference to" that object.

Am I doing something horribly wrong?

EDIT:
In response to quamrana's question, this is one of the output lines in the console when it attempts to build.

```
g++  -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/JAUSTester build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/MainScreen.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/moc_MainScreen.o    -L/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib/active /usr/local/lib/active/libcxutils.so -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib/active/libjauscore.so -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib/active/libjausextras.so -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib/active/libjausmobility.so -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib/active/libtinyxml.so -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
```

The .so files I want to include are the ones specified there in /usr/local/lib/active/.

Comment: Is it possible with NetBeans to check to see what command line it will use when linking?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the line as an edit.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: The auto-complete works because the project correctly references the header files. I'm not sure about the linker stage as I'm not familiar with the `-Wl,-rpath` option. I was expecting, first `-L/usr/local/lib/active` to tell the linker about the folder, then, `-lcxutils` etc (ie without the lib and without the .so) for each of the shared libraries.